# IntelliJ IDEA shortcut tips

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Is the shortcut key prompt on the picture a function of IDEA? How do I enable this feature?

Comment: The alternative for other OS makes me think it's likely added by whoever created the video/gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature provided by [Presentation Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7345-presentation-assistant) plugin.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html on how to manage plugins in IDEA.